# Dependabot can't evaluate your Python dependency files snowflake-connector-python / simple-salesforce

Tags: github, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, simple-salesforce, dependabot

In GitHub security I see a vulnerability alert that says:

> snowflake-connector-python is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial
> of Service (ReDoS)

When I click the button to create a security update for snowflake-connector-python
I see

> Dependabot failed to update your dependencies because there was an
> error evaluating your Python dependency files.
>
> Dependabot encountered the following error: Illformed requirement
> ["==0.24.2simple-salesforce>=0.74.2"]

However our simple-salesforce version is simple-salesforce==1.12.2